# Parse Google Transliteration Json using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I'm trying to get value from Google transliteration Json. Json code is looking like this:

```
[
  "SUCCESS",
  [
    [
      "hlo",
      [
        "jaisa",
        "jaisaa",
        "jaissa",
        "jaisaaa",
        "zaisa",
        "jaissaa"
      ],
      [],
      {
        "candidate_type": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      "ok",
      [
        "main",
        "mainn",
        "man",
        "mein",
        "mann",
        "meinn"
      ],
      [],
      {
        "candidate_type": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0
        ]
      }
    ]

  ]
]
```

my C# code to get value from json:

```
var userObj = JObject.Parse(jsontxt.Text.Trim());
wordstxt.Text = userObj[1][0][0].ToString();
```

There is no variable name to extract value from json code, I'm getting error like this:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. I'm trying to get value `hlo > jaisa`

Comment: Use `JArray.Parse` instead of `JObject.Parse`, given that the JSON document you've got represents an array, not an object.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. "var userObj = JArray.Parse(jsontxt.Text.Trim()); wordstxt.Text = userObj[1][0][0].ToString();" This is working and return **hlo**. But i want to get first value of **hlo**

Comment: So use `userObj[1][0][1]`, which is another array. Basically you need to look very carefully at the structure of the JSON, and work out what it is you need from that. Using a debugger to investigate `userObj` may well help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@JonSkeet** mentioned in comment section. You can parse this Json to [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) then use `userObj[1][0][1];` to get expected list.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jsonString = @"[
                  ""SUCCESS"",
                  [
                    [
                      ""hlo"",
                      [
                        ""jaisa"",
                        ""jaisaa"",
                        ""jaissa"",
                        ""jaisaaa"",
                        ""zaisa"",
                        ""jaissaa""
                      ],
                      [],
                      {
                        ""candidate_type"": [
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    [
                      ""ok"",
                      [
                        ""main"",
                        ""mainn"",
                        ""man"",
                        ""mein"",
                        ""mann"",
                        ""meinn""
                      ],
                      [],
                      {
                        ""candidate_type"": [
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    ]

                  ]
                ]";


    var userObj = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

    var expectedListValues = userObj[1][0][1];

    foreach (JToken item in expectedListValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output will be:

```
jaisa
jaisaa
jaissa
jaisaaa
zaisa
jaissaa
```

If you want to just take first item of this, you can use `userObj[1][0][1][0].ToString()` as well.